# Dynamic Hasura X-Hasura-Role with Apollo SubscriptionClient

Tags: next.js, react-apollo, hasura

What is the proper way to dynamically change the headers in Apollo SubscriptionClient based on the users role in Hasura?

Stack:

- NextJS
- Apollo
- Auth0
- Hasura (Stores Auth0_Id with Role column)

The goal here is to utilize Hasura roles for permissions. I know the JWT token has the allowed roles, but I want the ability to set the role based on the users assigned role. The path I am going down is querying Hasura user table for the role with the userID from auth0 via NextJS internal API.

**ApolloClient.js**

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws'
import { SubscriptionClient } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws'

let accessToken, role, user = null
const requestAccessToken = async () => {
  if (accessToken) return
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI}/api/session`)
  if (res.ok) {
    const json = await res.json()
    accessToken = json.accessToken
  } else {
    accessToken = 'public'
  }
}

const requestRole = async (userId) => {
  if (role) return
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_HOST}/api/role/"${userId}"`)
  if (res.ok) {
    const json = await res.json()
    console.log(json)
    role = json.data.vknursery_users_by_pk.role
  }
}

const requestUser = async () => {
  if (role) return
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_HOST}/api/me`)
  if (res.ok) {
    const json = await res.json()
    user = json
  }
}
// remove cached token on 401 from the server
const resetTokenLink = onError(({ networkError }) => {
  if (networkError && networkError.name === 'ServerError' && networkError.statusCode === 401) {
    accessToken = null
  }
})
const createHttpLink = (headers) => {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/v1/graphql`,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers, // auth token is fetched on the server side
    fetch,
  })
  return httpLink;
}
const createWSLink = () => {
  return new WebSocketLink(
    new SubscriptionClient(`wss://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/v1/graphql`, {
      lazy: true,
      reconnect: true,
      connectionParams: async () => {
        await requestAccessToken() // happens on the client
        await requestUser()
        await requestRole(user.sub) //get role from hasura to assign in apollo request headers
        return {
          headers: {
            'X-Hasura-Role': role,
            authorization: accessToken ? `Bearer ${accessToken}` : '',
          },
        }
      },
    })
  )
}
export default function createApolloClient(initialState, headers) {
  const ssrMode = typeof window === 'undefined'
  let link

  if (ssrMode) {
    link = createHttpLink(headers) // executed on server
  } else {
    link = createWSLink() // executed on client
  }
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode,
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState),
  })
}
```

**/api/role/[userId].js**

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

export default async function me(req, res) {
  const {
    query: { userId },
  } = req
  try {
    await fetch(`https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/v1/graphql`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'x-hasura-admin-secret': process.env.HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: `{ vknursery_users_by_pk( auth0_id:${userId}){ role } }` })
    })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(data => {
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data))
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message)
  }
}
```

**/api/me.js**

```
import auth0 from '../../lib/auth0'

export default async function me(req, res) {
  try {
    await auth0.handleProfile(req, res)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The role goes either as a join with the users table (you can keep the auth0 id here) or as **part of the JWT signed by auth0** (there's a Roles feature in its UI) or **as part of an authentication hook** (see Hasura's docs). Roles aren't given by the calling client, because normally you don't control its execution.